# windows 8 xaml inline hyperlink

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

How do I create properly formatted hyperlinks in Windows Store Apps in XAML?  I tried creating an inline hyperlink and want to style it with a staticresource:

```
          <RichTextBlock Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Paragraph>
                <Run>"A sentence with inline text "</Run>
                <InlineUIContainer>
                    <HyperlinkButton Background="Yellow">
                        my link
                    </HyperlinkButton>
                </InlineUIContainer>
                <Run>... some more text</Run>
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBlock>
```

i get the following where the hyperlink is not aligned with the rest of the sentence:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I tried this to no avail:

```
<RichTextBlock FontSize="20">
    <Paragraph Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light">
        <Run>Now is the time for</Run>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="all good men">
                <HyperlinkButton.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0"  FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
                                    Text="{Binding Content, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </HyperlinkButton.Template>
            </HyperlinkButton>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        <Run>to come to the aid of their country</Run>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

And so then I tried this:

```
<RichTextBlock FontSize="20">
    <Paragraph Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light">
        <Run>Now is the time for</Run>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped_1">
                <Underline><Run Text="all good men" /></Underline>
            </TextBlock>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        <Run>to come to the aid of their country</Run>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

This works like a charm!

[image]

I am not pretending it is not a little more work to implement your own hyperlink button but think of it this way - you will have 100% control over its layout! And it will easily inherit from the font styles around it!

Make sense?

Comment: yes.  i like this paradigm. thx. btw, what does the run tag do?

Comment: The run tag allows you to execute a binding inside a textblock. It also allows you to execute more than one binding by having more than one run in a single textblock. Google can tell you more.

Comment: i found that tap on textblock causes my event handler to be called twice.  i read a post regarding this issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438806/textbox-textchanged-event-firing-twice-on-windows-phone-7-emulator

Comment: Now, all that is left is to see how to make damn thing clickable... :(

Answer (score 7):

For future readers just to add that windows 8.1 simplify this task, Windows 8.1 adds the [Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.hyperlink.aspx) element to the XAML text object model in the Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents namespace, so now we can simply use it like this :

```
<RichTextBlock>
  <Paragraph FontSize="22">Please click on this <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.link.com">link</Hyperlink>, thanks !</Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

and it looks like this :

[image]

Comment: And what about changing default visited/unvisited colors for such hyperlink?

Comment: Hyperlink inherits from TextElement, so did you try to change Foreground property ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to resolve this as well and came up with the following:

```
<RichTextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<Paragraph xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" >
    <Run FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="24">A sentence with inline text</Run>
    <InlineUIContainer>
        <HyperlinkButton FontSize="24" Background="Gray" Foreground="Blue" Template="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonControlTemplate1}" BorderThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Padding="0" FontFamily="Calibri">
            the link with g
        </HyperlinkButton>
    </InlineUIContainer>
    <Run FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="24">and some more text</Run>
</Paragraph>
```

and the Template as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HyperlinkButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkDisabledThemeBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                To="1"
                                Duration="0" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                To="1"
                                Duration="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
                    Margin="1,0" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform TranslateY="8"/>
                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
            </ContentPresenter>

            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                Opacity="0"
                StrokeDashOffset="1.5" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                Opacity="0"
                StrokeDashOffset="0.5" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

The only caveat is that the `<CompositeTransform TranslateY="8"/>` must be set to 1/3 of the font size, in this case 8 since font size is 24. Not ideal, but it does produce the desired output.

Update:
or use the following, this was derived from looking at the Social Media Windows 8 Dashboard Sample at
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Social-Media-Dashboard-135436da

```
<Paragraph xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" >
<Run FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16">A sentence with inline text</Run>
<Span>
<InlineUIContainer>
        <HyperlinkButton FontSize="16" BorderThickness="0" Margin ="-10,-13" Foreground="Blue" FontFamily="Calibri">
        the link with g
    </HyperlinkButton>
</InlineUIContainer>
</Span>
<Run FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16">and some more text</Run>
```